# Ajax POST request to Restheart MongoDB service

Tags: jquery, ajax, mongodb, restheart

I am attempting to POST to a Restheart/MongoDB server using jQuery/ajax with some difficulty.  The response returned is as if I ran a GET and not a POST.  And it also appears that it is trying to execute the response as if it were a callback.  I am guessing that is because I am using jsonp (?).  But if I don't use jsonp, I get a CORS error (my db server is different from my development computer).  But I have my header set for Allow-Origin: *.  Thoughts?

```
    myHeaders = {"Authorization":"Basic " + 'user:password'.toString('base64'),
            "Content-Type":"application/json; charset=utf-8",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "*"
            }   

    $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    crossDomain: true,
    contentType: "application/json",
    headers: myHeaders,
    dataType : 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'jsonp', // mongod is expecting the parameter name to be called "jsonp"
      url: "http://mydomain:80/db/people",
      data: JSON.stringify({ "name": "John", "location": "Boston" }),
        success: function (data) {
    console.log('success' + data);
  },
  error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log('error', errorThrown);
  }
        })
```

[image]

Here is a screenshot of the error from Firefox when I try a GET request.  You can see I am passing the appropriate headers (I believe).

Comment: Are you sure that your server supports CORS? It doiesn't matter what headers you are putting on the client - if the server doesn't support CORS then you can forget about making a cross domain AJAX call to it. In this case you might need to write a bridge script on your domain.

Comment: I know that Restheart supports CORS (https://softinstigate.atlassian.net/wiki/display/RH/CORS+Support).

Comment: Note you cannot send POST requests for JSONP, when you send JSONP it  basically creates a `script` tag with desired URL and uses GET to call it.

Answer (score 0):

you should not use JSONP with RESTHeart, since it supports CORS.

try (I haven't tried the code...)

```
var myHeaders = {"Authorization":"Basic " + 'user:password'.toString('base64'),
             "Content-Type":"application/json; charset=utf-8" }; 

$.ajax("http://mydomain:80/db/people", { method: "POST",
     crossDomain: true,
     contentType: "application/json",
     headers: myHeaders,
     dataType : 'json',
     jsonp: false,
     data: JSON.stringify({ "name": "John", "location": "Boston" })
})
.done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) { console.log(textStatus) }))
.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) { console.log('error', textStatus) });
```

Comment: Thanks, but no luck.  I remove jsonp and I get a CORS error, despite sending the necessary header information.  I added a screenshot to my question as illustration.

Comment: looking at your screenshot, it seems to me that the problem is you passing the Access-Control-Allow-Header and Access-Control-Allow-Origin as request headers. You shouldn't; these are response headers in charge of the server.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with header

`var myHeaders = {"Authorization":"Basic " + 'user:password'.toString('base64'),
             "Content-Type":"application/json; charset=utf-8" };`

Use btoa() function of javascript to convert to string to base64.

`btoa("userid:password")`

So, final header string will loog like

`var myHeaders = {"Authorization":"Basic " + btoa("userid:password"),
             "Content-Type":"application/json; charset=utf-8" };`